# get the value of the property from the array of objects. objects with children

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, iteration

I am trying to get from here :

```
var example=[
    {
        "value": 4,
        "label": "Bangalore",
        "path": "fa fa-tachometer",
        "parentmenu": null,
        "layout": null,
        "children": [
            {
                "value": 5,
                "label": "HSR Layout",
                "path": "fa fa-tachometer",
                "parentmenu": 4,
                "layout": null,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "value": 6,
                        "label": "Building1",
                        "path": "fa fa-tachometer",
                        "parentmenu": 5,
                        "layout": null,
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "value": 7,
                                "label": "Floor1",
                                "path": "fa fa-tachometer",
                                "parentmenu": 6,
                                "layout": null,
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "value": 8,
                                        "label": "Telemon_12765213",
                                        "path": "fa fa-tachometer",
                                        "parentmenu": 7,
                                        "layout": null,
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "value": 9,
                                                "label": "Battery",
                                                "path": "fa fa-tachometer",
                                                "parentmenu": 8,
                                                "layout": null,
                                                "children": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 10,
                                                "label": "MSensor",
                                                "path": "fa fa-tachometer",
                                                "parentmenu": 8,
                                                "layout": null,
                                                "children": []
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": 11,
                                        "label": "Telemon_12765245",
                                        "path": "fa fa-tachometer",
                                        "parentmenu": 7,
                                        "layout": null,
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "value": 12,
                                                "label": "Battery",
                                                "path": "fa fa-tachometer",
                                                "parentmenu": 11,
                                                "layout": null,
                                                "children": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 13,
                                                "label": "MSensor",
                                                "path": "fa fa-tachometer",
                                                "parentmenu": 11,
                                                "layout": null,
                                                "children": []
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "value": 14,
                                "label": "Floor2",
                                "path": "fa fa-tachometer",
                                "parentmenu": 6,
                                "layout": null,
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "value": 15,
                                        "label": "Telemon_12765248",
                                        "path": "fa fa-tachometer",
                                        "parentmenu": 14,
                                        "layout": null,
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "value": 16,
                                                "label": "Battery",
                                                "path": "fa fa-tachometer",
                                                "parentmenu": 15,
                                                "layout": null,
                                                "children": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 17,
                                                "label": "MSensor",
                                                "path": "fa fa-tachometer",
                                                "parentmenu": 15,
                                                "layout": null,
                                                "children": []
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 18,
                        "label": "Building2",
                        "path": "fa fa-tachometer",
                        "parentmenu": 5,
                        "layout": null,
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "value": 19,
                                "label": "Floor1",
                                "path": "fa fa-tachometer",
                                "parentmenu": 18,
                                "layout": null,
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "value": 20,
                                        "label": "Telemon_12765254",
                                        "path": "fa fa-tachometer",
                                        "parentmenu": 19,
                                        "layout": null,
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "value": 21,
                                                "label": "Battery",
                                                "path": "fa fa-tachometer",
                                                "parentmenu": 20,
                                                "layout": null,
                                                "children": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 22,
                                                "label": "MSensor",
                                                "path": "fa fa-tachometer",
                                                "parentmenu": 20,
                                                "layout": null,
                                                "children": []
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

to here:

```
var a=[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20];
```

Obviously I could just loop it and build the array but I could just get the keys from the parent but I want the values of all the objects. parents as well children.

Comment: _"I could just loop it and build the array but "_ you are going to have to loop in some way in either case, you are dealing with arrays

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3):

Try with [`JSON.parse()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjmsKG79OfWAhXMpY8KHYX1BgYQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FJSON%2Fparse&usg=AOvVaw2rlrlfBughOgfN_lUh-Px9).match the `value` name key then push the respected `values` to the array

```js
var example = [{ "value": 4, "label": "Bangalore", "path": "fa fa-tachometer", "parentmenu": null, "layout": null, "children": [{ "value": 5, "label": "HSR Layout", "path": "fa fa-tachometer", "parentmenu": 4, "layout": null, "children": [{ "value": 6, "label": "Building1", "path": "fa fa-tachometer", "parentmenu": 5, "layout": null, "children": [{ "value": 7, "label": "Floor1", "path": "fa fa-tachometer", "parentmenu": 6, "layout": null, "children": [{ "value": 8, "label": "Telemon_12765213", "path": "fa fa-tachometer", "parentmenu": 7, "layout": null, "children": [{ "value": 9, "label": "Battery", "path": "fa fa-tachometer", "parentmenu": 8, "layout": null, "children": [] }, { "value": 10, "label": "MSensor", "path": "fa fa-tachometer", "parentmenu": 8, "layout": null, "children": [] }] }, { "value": 11, "label": "Telemon_12765245", "path": "fa fa-tachometer", "parentmenu": 7, "layout": null, "children": [{ "value": 12, "label": "Battery", "path": "fa fa-tachometer", "parentmenu": 11, "layout": null, "children": [] }, { "value": 13, "label": "MSensor", "path": "fa fa-tachometer", "parentmenu": 11, "layout": null, "children": [] }] }] }, { "value": 14, "label": "Floor2", "path": "fa fa-tachometer", "parentmenu": 6, "layout": null, "children": [{ "value": 15, "label": "Telemon_12765248", "path": "fa fa-tachometer", "parentmenu": 14, "layout": null, "children": [{ "value": 16, "label": "Battery", "path": "fa fa-tachometer", "parentmenu": 15, "layout": null, "children": [] }, { "value": 17, "label": "MSensor", "path": "fa fa-tachometer", "parentmenu": 15, "layout": null, "children": [] }] }] }] }, { "value": 18, "label": "Building2", "path": "fa fa-tachometer", "parentmenu": 5, "layout": null, "children": [{ "value": 19, "label": "Floor1", "path": "fa fa-tachometer", "parentmenu": 18, "layout": null, "children": [{ "value": 20, "label": "Telemon_12765254", "path": "fa fa-tachometer", "parentmenu": 19, "layout": null, "children": [{ "value": 21, "label": "Battery", "path": "fa fa-tachometer", "parentmenu": 20, "layout": null, "children": [] }, { "value": 22, "label": "MSensor", "path": "fa fa-tachometer", "parentmenu": 20, "layout": null, "children": [] }] }] }] }] }] }];

var res =[]
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(example), function(keys,values){
if(keys == 'value')
 res.push(values)
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: What if I want to get the values of only parent i.e object having children array ?

 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20]

Comment: this is kind of clever, but it heavily relies on the internal mechanism for parsing. then it needs to stringify the object first, which is an overhead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the recursive function to reach each node like this.

```
var arr = [];
function getValues(example){
    example.forEach(function(obj){
        //check if object has children i.e. it is a parent
        if(obj.children.length){
            arr.push(obj.value);
            getValues(obj.children);
        }
    });
}

getValues(example);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: What if I want to get the values of only parent i.e object having children array ? [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20]

Comment: Hi @VikramMaiya I updated my answer according to your query. Please check it and give your feedback

Comment: Thank you Rohith Agrawal.  
How to convert a value property type from number to string and store it in a same array.

From Here:
[{ value: 4, label: "Bangalore", path: "fa fa-tachometer"........] 
To Here:
[{ value: "4", label: "Bangalore", path: "fa fa-tachometer"........]

Comment: Hi @VikramMaiya, you can use this `arr[0].value = arr[0].value.toString();` to convert a value property type from number to string and store it in a same array. Also please upvote for the answers which you find it helpful

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iterative an recursive approach and check if the children have a length.

```js
var data = [{ value: 4, label: "Bangalore", path: "fa fa-tachometer", parentmenu: null, layout: null, children: [{ value: 5, label: "HSR Layout", path: "fa fa-tachometer", parentmenu: 4, layout: null, children: [{ value: 6, label: "Building1", path: "fa fa-tachometer", parentmenu: 5, layout: null, children: [{ value: 7, label: "Floor1", path: "fa fa-tachometer", parentmenu: 6, layout: null, children: [{ value: 8, label: "Telemon_12765213", path: "fa fa-tachometer", parentmenu: 7, layout: null, children: [{ value: 9, label: "Battery", path: "fa fa-tachometer", parentmenu: 8, layout: null, children: [] }, { value: 10, label: "MSensor", path: "fa fa-tachometer", parentmenu: 8, layout: null, children: [] }] }, { value: 11, label: "Telemon_12765245", path: "fa fa-tachometer", parentmenu: 7, layout: null, children: [{ value: 12, label: "Battery", path: "fa fa-tachometer", parentmenu: 11, layout: null, children: [] }, { value: 13, label: "MSensor", path: "fa fa-tachometer", parentmenu: 11, layout: null, children: [] }] }] }, { value: 14, label: "Floor2", path: "fa fa-tachometer", parentmenu: 6, layout: null, children: [{ value: 15, label: "Telemon_12765248", path: "fa fa-tachometer", parentmenu: 14, layout: null, children: [{ value: 16, label: "Battery", path: "fa fa-tachometer", parentmenu: 15, layout: null, children: [] }, { value: 17, label: "MSensor", path: "fa fa-tachometer", parentmenu: 15, layout: null, children: [] }] }] }] }, { value: 18, label: "Building2", path: "fa fa-tachometer", parentmenu: 5, layout: null, children: [{ value: 19, label: "Floor1", path: "fa fa-tachometer", parentmenu: 18, layout: null, children: [{ value: 20, label: "Telemon_12765254", path: "fa fa-tachometer", parentmenu: 19, layout: null, children: [{ value: 21, label: "Battery", path: "fa fa-tachometer", parentmenu: 20, layout: null, children: [] }, { value: 22, label: "MSensor", path: "fa fa-tachometer", parentmenu: 20, layout: null, children: [] }] }] }] }] }] }],
    values = data.reduce(function iter(r, a) {
        return a.children && a.children.length
            ? r.concat(a.value,  a.children.reduce(iter, []))
            : r;
    }, []);

console.log(values);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```